# Since full path cannot be accessed from file input tag, how do I reload a file already uploaded in A.html, in B.html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a website where I want to load a file (called example.obj) in B.html that was uploaded in A.html. Since I cannot get the full path of the example.obj both A.html and B.html, what are my options?

Comment: That's completely impossible.  You need to store it on the server.

Comment: @SLaks: how would I go about doing this? I'm working with .obj files.